# Lumen + Dingo + JWT = Error 401

Tags: laravel, jwt, lumen, dingo-api

I'm using this package for my project : https://github.com/krisanalfa/lumen-jwt

My project was working perfectly on my local server but not when i make it online.

I can login successfully, the token is generated but after that, each request receive a 401 error.

```
Failed to authenticate because of bad credentials or an invalid authorization header.
```

like the token is not right but it is there and it's right. I tried to run a local server on my server and send some curl request locally it is working. But remote curl request doesn;t work.

i'm on this problem since more than 2 days and i couldn't find the issue. All debug i did led me to a server problem but what ?

Any help ?